# Can't loop XML parse with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, xml, parsing, post

I am trying to extract text from XML in a such way:
    [text] [choice in text] [text continues] [another text] [another choice] [another text continues]

I've managed to do this partially, so it extracts the first paragraph and the choices for the first paragraph, but it doesn't extract the choices for the second paragraph, no idea why. (In the example the choices are the same for the first and second paragraph).

Furthermore I'm using AJAX to post the index of the selected choice to php and to mysql, but I don't have any idea how I could separate the choices. (Like: first choice-->1; second choice-->3; etc.)

My code is:

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
var myArray = [];
var i = 0;

//Megkeressük az összes paragrafust
$(xml).find("Paragraph").each(function()
{   
    $(this).find("text").each(function(){
    {

        $("#wrapper").append('<div id="text">' + $(this).text()) + '</div><br />';
    $("#text").append('<div id="choice"></div>');   

    }       
});         
});

//Each paragraph
$(xml).find("Paragraph").each(function()
{  //Megkeressük az összes választékot  
$(this).find("choice").each(function()
{
    myArray.push($(this).text());

 });
});

 $("#choice").append('&nbsp;' + myArray[i] + '&nbsp;');
    sendValue(i); 


$("#choice").click(function() {

    if(i + 1 >=  myArray.length)
    {
            i=0;
            $("#choice").html('&nbsp;' + myArray[i] + '&nbsp;');
            sendValue(i);   
    }       

    else
    {       i++;
            $("#choice").html('&nbsp;' + myArray[i] + '&nbsp;');        
            sendValue(i); 
    }

});

function sendValue(str){

// post(file, data, callback, type); (only "file" is required)
$.post(

"ajax.php", //Ajax file

{ sendValue: str },  // create an object will all values

//function that is called when server returns a value.
function(data){
    $('#i').text(data.returnValue);
}, 

//How you want the data formated when it is returned from the server.
"json"
);

}

}
```

The PHP:

```
<?php 

//Get Post Variables. The name is the same as 
//what was in the object that was sent in the jQuery
if (isset($_POST['sendValue'])){
$value = $_POST['sendValue'];   
}else{
$value = "";
}

//Because we want to use json, we have to place things in an array and encode it for json.
//This will give us a nice javascript object on the front side.
 echo json_encode(array("returnValue"=>"This is returned from PHP : ".$value));  

?>
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page1>
<Paragraph>
<text>This is the first text in the</text><choice>paragraph</choice><choice>book</choice><choice>mádörfákör</choice><choice>asd</choice><text>after which the text continues.</text>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph>
<text>This is the SECOND text in the</text><choice>paragraph</choice><choice>book</choice><choice>mádörfákör</choice><choice>asd</choice><text>after which the second text continues.</text>
</Paragraph>
</Page1>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$(xml).find("Paragraph").each(function() {
    var paragraph = $('<div class="paragraph"></div>');
    paragraph.appendTo('#wrapper');

    var choiceCount = 0;
    $(this).find("text,choice").each(function() {
        if ($(this).get(0).tagName == 'TEXT') {
            $('<span class="paragraph-text"></span>').appendTo(paragraph).text($(this).text());
        } else {
            var choice = $('<span class="paragraph-choice"></span>').appendTo(paragraph).text($(this).text());
            (function(choiceCount) {
                choice.click(function() {
                    sendValue(choiceCount);
                });
            })(choiceCount);
            choiceCount++;
        }
    });
});
```

Saved (and working) here: http://jsfiddle.net/XSuBU/1/

Comment: This actually looks quite good, thank you, the only problem is, that it puts the choices next to eachother instead of a single div, which changes its text on click.. (loops through an array) and I really need that array because of the index which whill be sent to mysql

Comment: I've kept the index — it's what I've called `choiceCount`. If you open the jsfiddle page I even alert that index when clicking a choice. As to the styling, of course you can write the CSS rules however you'd like. Add `display: block;` if they need to be block-level (or even change the `<span>` to a `<div>` if you'd like.)

Comment: Sorry mate, I cant get it to work. Copied your exact code but it doesn't even show the paragraph texts. I was thinking about counting the paragraph elements and then putting them into a for loop.

Comment: It sounds like there may be some error. If you recreate your setup on jsfiddle (or any similar site) it would be easier to diagnose. The sample I have up there is definitely functioning, at least with the sample XML you provided.